# before_session hook failed: Pry::CommandError: Cannot locate this method: load

Tags: ruby, pry

Loading up the Pry REPL in a Ruby script I get this odd error:

```
before_session hook failed: Pry::CommandError: Cannot locate this method: load.
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/pry-0.9.12.2/lib/pry/method.rb:498:in `pry_doc_info'
(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Notes:
1. The code seems to execute fine other than that cryptic message and
2. I can't find a "`_pry_.hooks.errors`" file

Comment: I've the same problem, and also no solution.  I can say that '_pry_.hooks.errors' isn't a file, it's a variable.  Try puts _pry_.hooks.errors...  (although this did little to help me...)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this using Ruby 2.4.1 and Pry Stack Explorer, in a Gemfile with:

```
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-rescue'
gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
```

On inserting the Pry Debugger, I saw:

```
before_session hook failed: Pry::CommandError: Cannot locate this method: load. Invoke the 'gem-install pry-doc' Pry command to get access to Ruby Core documentation.
/Users/alexharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/method.rb:489:in `pry_doc_info'
(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)
```

Then I tried following the instructions about *pry*.hooks.errors:

```
[2] pry(#<MarkdownLint::Rule>)> puts _pry_.hooks.errors
Cannot locate this method: load. Invoke the 'gem-install pry-doc' Pry command to get access to Ruby Core documentation.
=> nil
```

So I just added pry-doc to my Gemfile. Then, I still had another issue. On trying to exit the debugger:

```
[2] pry(#<MarkdownLint::Rule>)>
when_started hook failed: NameError: uninitialized constant RubyVM::DebugInspector
/Users/alexharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/binding_of_caller-0.8.0/lib/binding_of_caller/mri2.rb:21:in `callers'
(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)
```

And I found I could solve that one by requesting not the latest version of debug_inspector.

In the end, to successfully use pry and pry-stack_explorer, I ended up with:

```
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-rescue'
gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
gem 'pry-doc'
gem 'debug_inspector', '<= 0.0.2'
```

Comment: How were you able to create a pry session in that 2nd code block when the breakpoint failed in the 1st code block?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I haven't shown any code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

From the source it looks like the hook possible raised an exception but then swallowed it. The comment above `exec_hook` recommends that you interrogate `$pry_hook_error` to find out what happened.

```
# Execute the specified hook.
# @param [Symbol] name The hook name to execute
# @param [*Object] args The arguments to pass to the hook
# @return [Object, Exception] The return value of the hook or the exception raised
#
# If executing a hook raises an exception, we log that and then continue sucessfully.
# To debug such errors, use the global variable $pry_hook_error, which is set as a
# result.
def exec_hook(name, *args, &block)
  e_before = hooks.errors.size
  hooks.exec_hook(name, *args, &block).tap do
    hooks.errors[e_before..-1].each do |e|
      output.puts "#{name} hook failed: #{e.class}: #{e.message}"
      output.puts "#{e.backtrace.first}"
      output.puts "(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)"
    end
  end
end
```

I've not been able to reproduce this so please forgive me if this is wildly off base.